# Parsing CSV file in Hadoop

Tags: csv, hadoop

How can Mapreduce parse a CSV file with 80 columns and for each row in excel format it results two to three lines in CSV format? Text input format doesn't work in this case. Does key value input format work in this case?

Comment: Don't understand; correct your grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own InoutFormat & RecordReader which will read multiple lines and send as a single record to your Mapper.